# Plumbing/venting outside of studs

Tags: plumbing, installation, studs

Getting ready to start plumbing on new house. Just wondered if I could plumb/vent outside of existing wall and build another wall in front of it. It would eliminate drilling through studs and alot of aggravation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes indeedy - it's called a plumbing chase, and quite common. Toss in some conduits as well as the pipes and it will also help with your network/cable wiring.

Comment: Would these plumbing spaces be all the way from the floor to the ceiling? How many rooms would be done that way? Would they be only on some walls and those exterior walls? Have you seen examples of this idea?